# Swift UI - setting View for both iPad and iPhone

Tags: swiftui, constraints

I am new to using Swift UI and am coding a simple app to learn. I want the views to look the same on iPad as they do on iPhone, however the iPad shows a blank screen where the view just out of bounds. I've tried to use `GeometryReader` as follows in an attempt to fix:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { bounds in
                VStack(alignment: .center){
                    Text("Welcome to Fair Rent")
                        .font(Font.system(size: 30, design: .rounded))
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .frame(width: nil)
                    Image(systemName: "person.3.fill")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(2)
                    Text("How many people do you live with?")
                        .font(Font.system(size:20, design: .rounded))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .lineLimit(nil)
                        .padding(18.0)
                    NavigationLink(destination: FairRentView(viewModel: FairRentViewModel(Amounts(), housemates: 1)))
                    {
                        Text("      1 other person")
                            .styledLinkLabel(with: gradient)
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: FairRentView(viewModel: FairRentViewModel(Amounts(), housemates: 2)))
                    {
                        Text("      2 other people")
                            .styledLinkLabel(with: gradient)
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: FairRentView(viewModel: FairRentViewModel(Amounts(), housemates: 3)))
                    {
                        Text("      3 other people")
                            .styledLinkLabel(with: gradient)
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height)
            }.navigationBarTitle("Fair Rent", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction of how to do this properly in Swift UI? Thanks

Comment: I assume you wanted `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` for `NavigationView`

Comment: What does this do @Asperi ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NavigationViewStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationviewstyle)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                Text("Tap Me")
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("ContentView"))
                Text("Hello, I'm a Detail View")
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()) 
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, I'm a Detail View")
    }
}
```

**iPad:**

[image]

**iPhone:**

[image]